# Rewrite SQL query as a prepared statement and use in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, wpdb

I have a sql query that I use to populate a table with data. It looks like this

```
<?php 

   $client = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT concat (string, string2), type FROM `file` WHERE `code` = incoming AND `status` = new");

 $header = array("concat", "type");

  echo "<thead><tr>";
  foreach ($header as $list) {
          echo '<th >' . $list . '</th>';
        }
        echo "<thead></tr>";
  foreach ($client as $key => $value) {
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ( $value as $a ) {

              $url = get_template_directory_uri();

              if ($counter == 0) {
                echo '<td><a href="'.$url.'/mywebsiteurl/' . $a . '">'. htmlspecialchars($a) .' </a></td>';
              } else {
                echo '<td>'. htmlspecialchars($a) .'</td>';
              }
              $counter++;  
                 }   
            echo '</tr>';
  }
```

Now after adding search filters, I have realized that maybe it would be better if I use a prepared statement. I have tried rewriting my query following WP codex but I get errors. I've been trying with prepare().

How do I do this and will I be able to extract the data in a foreach loop using the prepared statement?

Comment: What errors did you get? What does your try with prepare() look like? Also, note that `$wpdb->prepare()` isn't working with what is commonly understood as prepared statements in databases. It returns simple SQL that is safe to execute with $wbpb->query(), $wpdb->get_var() etc.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. So if I have $wpdb->prepare() I would still need to use $wpdb->get_results and then pass them in a foreach loop? What would be the purpose of doing it then? I'll edit the OP with the errors I get shortly

Comment: The main point is that you don't have to worry about escaping data when you use ->prepare with printf-like placeholders, e.g. `->prepare("... meta_key = %s", $meta_key)`. Using it helps you protect yourself against SQL-injections.